# How to edit web pages in browser in real time like visualwebsiteoptimizer.com?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to enable in-browser editing of a web page, as done in following video (demo of visualwebsiteoptimizer.com)?

(see video at 0:15)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy89HnIJsE4&feature=plcp

Basically, what I wish is to be able to:

- take a copy of a web page, (that part is ok),
- somehow enable edit mode (as would be done in any text editor),
- click on the element I wish to edit, and be able to modify the selected element

---

Edit: sorry I wasn't clear enough: my end goal is to enable my users to do live editing online (as done by visualwebsiteoptimizer.com) in a visual way.

Comment: There are a lot of developer plugins for FireFox that allows this. Just search on Google.

Comment: `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true';document.designMode='on'; void 0`

Comment: I guess what you are searching for is "frontend editing" – which is feature any good, modern CMS has.

Comment: @feeela What if I am working outside any CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use designMode=on on the document, or contentEditable=true on specific elements. See for a small demo http://html5demos.com/contenteditable/. In addition, you could also catch mouseclicks and keydowns with jQuery and check the target element as to show options like CSS etc..!

Answer (score 2):

1 - use google chrome.

2 - hit ctrl + shift + i

3 - go to elements tab

4 - right click on the html you want to edit and select "edit as html" or double click in the text you want to change in that tab

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. I wish that my online users/clients can do live editing, so what you propose would not work.

Comment: @tucson editing and saving the edited data right? just like the profile editing in facebook.

Comment: @tucson well all of them answered live editing techniques, but not saving the data. As soon as you reload the page, the editing is gone to oblivion.

Comment: @Dexter Huinda Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Any way to save the data? VisualWebsiteOptimizer seem to manage to save the data somehow...

Comment: @tucson To save the data, you can use ajax to handle that part, saving data in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **Jelliphy**. Jelliphy is a tool that allows any users to edit any text of a web page, to move and resize elements in the page, to draw on the page, to edit the images and much more.

[Jelliphy Lite](http://www.dispage.com/?show_bookmarklet) and [Jelliphy Extended](http://www.dispage.com/?show_bookmarklet=ext) are bookmarklets that you can use with any browser for free: just go to the page to change and click the Jelliphy link from your favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, enjoy: [http://myedit.io](http://myedit.io/)